# Importing citation style to Zotero from Citavi

Tags: applications

I am a Mac user so I can't use Citavi. 
My institute has its own citation style but they only provide a Citavi citation file. I don't know a way to import a Citavi citation file into Endnote, Zotero or Mendeley so I don't have to use Windows.... 
Do you have a tip for me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that there is no way to do that. Citavi citation styles are in their own format and there is no conversion tool.
[There is a tool](http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/) for Zotero/Mendeley styles that let's you find close matches that you may found useful.